# Check if object is looking at position

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js, coordinates

I'm trying to check if an object (`this.target`) is looking at a specific position (`newPosition`). What I have right now is the following:

```
new THREE.Matrix4().lookAt( newPosition, this.target.position, this.target.up ) == this.target.matrix
```

But for some reason, this won't work. How are you meant to check if an Object3D is looking at a specific position?

Comment: `Object3D.getWorldDirection( resultVector )` will give you the direction the object is looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work because the matrix for your target is not in the same place, and can be scaled differently and all sorts of stuff.

A better technique is to raycast from your eye object, and see if it hits the target object.

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_terrain_raycast

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

// See if the ray from the camera into the world hits one of our meshes
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( mesh );
```

Comment: Okay, thanks @Flux! It's just that I've heard raycasting is an expensive operation and stuff. Any idea how expensive it really is?

Comment: You can always benchmark it with console.time()

However, computers are very fast, and so is Javascript. Even in games like Half Life 2 which is 10+ years old the player entity is constantly shooting a raycast to the floor every frame for many operations. If you're afraid of a perf hit, you can raycast on every nth frame.

One thing you can do is raycast only against certain sets of objects (which the THREE raycaster allows) so that you can filter against objects you only want to cast.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I only needed it for the player anyway, so I guess I was just thinking about micro-optimisation too early (root of all evil). The raycast reads perfectly, too!